# Is there a possibility to have a file located nex to the index.php (Apache Webserver) which can be read/written like a database?

Tags: php, xml, database, apache

I am trying to code a website where I need an easy DB with about 3 tables.
The problem is I don't get a database from the Admin of the Network and do not have any rights on the Web server but I can place files there. 
Currently, I am testing locally with xamp and an Apache server.

My question now is: is there a possibility that I have a file which is like a DB on the web server (maybe XML or CSV)? It should be possible to open/edit the file with PHP 5. If yes, what would you recommend as the best solution?

Comment: [SQLite](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/book.sqlite3.php) can help you. It has it's own connector for pdo and many ORMs. But you should store this file out of webroot.

Comment: Thank you would have stored it there if you hadn't warned me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have many options, some of them you listed. You could use `xml`, `csv`, or `yaml`.

It'll depend really on what exactly you want to save. Those file formats do not work quite like a database and may be quite limiting. If you have the proper software already on the software your best bet is likely to use [SQLite](https://www.sqlite.org/index.html) as it is stored as a file.